# 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple dummy sql with my dummy head:(

```
select if(`linktype`="group", (select contactgroups.grname 
                               from contactgroups, groupmembers 
                                   on contactgroups.id=groupmembers.id),2) 
from groupmembers
```

this should list only the groups name but I can't see what I've done wrong again:( Any help, please?

Another try:

```
SELECT contactgroups.grname
FROM contactgroups, groupmembers
WHERE contactgroups.id = groupmembers.id
```

works well gives 2 group names back. So this is why the error message. But if I select from groupmembers it should match with the groupmembers.group_id with the contactgroups.id

Comment: if must return a scalar value. Never tested it but try to substitute contactgroups.grname with group_concat(contactgroups.grname)

Comment: @nick you should post that as an answer

Comment: @Adrian. Did it. Hope it works. I'll try asap. ;)

Comment: the task would be to give me back a group name if likntype=group from the other table.

Comment: @JohnFx. Thanks I need to care about the format more you are right

Answer (score 1):

`if` must return a scalar value. 
Never tested it but try to substitute `contactgroups.grname` with `group_concat(contactgroups.grname)`

Comment: thanks for the comment it doesn't give error message anymore! that's good but still no luck with the group name:(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are including the groupMembers table in the subquery, but how about this alternative:

```
SELECT IF(`linktype`="group", (SELECT contactgroups.grname 
                               FROM contactgroups 
                               WHERE contactgroups.id=groupmembers.id),2) 
FROM groupmembers
```

or better yet, get rid of the subquery altogether as it is not needed

```
SELECT IF(`linktype`="group", contactgroups.grname,2) 
FROM groupmembers
LEFT JOIN contactgroups ON (contactgroups.id = groupmembers.id)
```

Also, I have a sneaking suspicion that your contactgroups table has multiple entries for one or more of your groupmembers table entries. You might want to confirm that too.

Answer (score -1):

The nested select

```
(select contactgroups.grname on contactgroups.id=groupmembers.id)
```

seems to return more than 1 row, You could use `LIMIT` to restrict this. Or if it's not expected, check your data.